# How to convert HDR video to SDR video on iOS using swift without custom libraries or ffmpeg

Tags: swift, avfoundation

How do you convert an HDR video to an SDR video using swift without custom libraries or ffmpeg?

Answer (score 1):

Using [AVAssetExportSession](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avassetexportsession) you can easily convert any video from HDR to SDR without going deeper into the AVFoundation or VideoToolbox stack.

Important to note here is that **this will only work using non HEVC presets such as these H.264 presets:**

- `AVAssetExportPresetLowQuality`
- `AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality`
- `AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality`
- `AVAssetExportPreset1920x1080` or any other resolution

[AVAssetExportSession Presets](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avassetexportsession/export_presets)

Unfortunately Apples documentation does not clearly state how to convert HDR to SDR except very briefly in this talk: [Export HDR media in your app with AVFoundation](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10010/) at about minute 09:30.

```
import AVFoundation
private func transcodeVideo(using inputVideoURL: URL, outputVideoURL: URL){
        
        //-----HELPER
        func reportProgressForAsyncExportSessionAndWait(exportSession: AVAssetExportSession, group: DispatchGroup) {
            while exportSession.status == .waiting || exportSession.status == .exporting {
                print("progress: \(exportSession.progress)")
                _ = group.wait(timeout: DispatchTime(uptimeNanoseconds: 1000 * NSEC_PER_MSEC))
            }
            print("TRANSCODE COMPLETED")
        }
        //-----
        
        let dg = DispatchGroup()
        
        let urlAsset:AVURLAsset = AVURLAsset(url: inputVideoURL)
        if let exporter = AVAssetExportSession(asset: urlAsset, presetName: AVAssetExportPreset1920x1080){
            exporter.outputURL = outputVideoURL
            //exporter.outputFileType = .mp4
            dg.enter()
            exporter.exportAsynchronously {
                dg.leave()
            }
            
            reportProgressForAsyncExportSessionAndWait(exportSession: exporter, group: dg)
        }else{
           // Error handling
        }
    }
```